# Why does this datepicker example from jqueryui's site no longer work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Why does this code no longer work? It's a copy and paste from the jquery ui examples page. It used to just work and now it no longer does.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works for me, except for the styles (for obvious reasons..) What does not work for you? Also, do you see any console errors? Note that `//` does not work for `file:///` protocol. You need to explicitly use `http://` or `https://`

Comment: define doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bozrxa30/1/ works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygpfzxhx/) to see a working example.

You have to include all the necessary scripts and styles. Have a look at the `External Ressources` in the jsfiddle configuration panel.

You can remove:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

It's not necessary to make the datepicker works. It's just the stylesheet of the demo!

Hope it's useful!